# Chrome Extension - background.js doesn't trigger when it's a "original" load, but with refresh it does

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've been working on an Chrome extension, which adds a download button to the YouTube video page.

I'm having some problems getting the button to show when you do the following..

- Visit YouTube -> Click on video = No button will show
- Refresh page = Button shows
- Open link in new tab = Button shows

So when a new video (page) loads in the same tab, the button doesn't show. I am using the background.js to append the button to the div class by id. I've tried using the document.ready in jQuery, and many more, but it still won't work.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "Name",
"version": "1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Description",
"background_page": "background.html",
"icons": { 
            "16":"icon-16.png", 
            "48":"icon-48.png", 
            "128":"icon-128.png" 
    }, 
"content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "jquery.min.js", "background.js" ],
"matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
 }]
}
```

**background.js**

```
$("#watch-like-dislike-buttons").append("<span><button style='border-color:#c6c6c6;background:#f0f0f0;box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10);' class='yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-text yt-uix-button-has-icon  yt-uix-tooltip' type='button' title='Download from site' id='dl-video' data-force-position='true' data-orientation='vertical' data-like-tooltip='Download from site' data-position='bottomright' data-button-toggle='true' data-tooltip-text='Download from site'><span class='yt-uix-button-icon-wrapper'><img src='http://site.net/img/icon-youtube-download.png' width='20' height='20' class='yt-uix-button-icon' alt='Download from site'></span><span style='margin-right:5px;color:#000;' class='yt-uix-button-content'>Download video </span></button></span>");

$('#dl-video').click(function(){
window.location = "http://site.net/?url=" + $(location).attr('href');
});
```

Can someone tell me why it won't append the button, when it's a "original load" by link on same tab. Thanks

Comment: Is that your entire content script? (It's very confusing that your content script is called `background.js` :o.)

Comment: Yes, it's all. I started learning this stuff today, so I'm a total newbie at this.. :P But when I click a hyperlink on the youtube home page, it doesn't append the button. It's first when I hit refresh or F5 that it appends the button, do you know why? Thanks

Comment: It's injecting fine for me as far as I can see.. When you say hyperlink on youtube home page you just mean the video links right?

Comment: I'm talking when your clicking one of the videos at the right side, then it changes link, but it doesn't append the button. At least not for me.

Comment: It's appending it fine for me for that case. Maybe you have an adblocker or something stopping it? I presume you've checked your console for errors?

Comment: I tried to disable Adblock plus, but it still didn't show the button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56893/discussion-between-anders-and-judgeja).

Comment: Youtube doesn't reload the page when you click on the videos. So your script injected and run only once when page has been loaded for the first time.